# Digital Music Rights - content usage rights

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, windows-media-player, groove-music

I recorded all of my CD's by burning them onto my PC with Windows Media Player. I have all of the .wma files and they cannot be opened by any media source I've tried, be it Groove Music or VLC or Windows Media Player.

I'm told by;

VLC PLayer - Could not demux ASF stream:
DRM protected streams are not supported.
VLC can't recognize the input's format:

Windows Media Player - encountered a problem while playing the file.

Groove Music says - Try playing this with a different player. This application doesn't have content usage rights.

I've looked and looked for a solution and I can't find what I'm looking for. I'm quite a novice regarding digital music, and I really want to play my cd's.

Comment: You “burned” your CDs incorrectly.  There is no solution to your problem other than doing it correctly.

Comment: @sasha - The only solution to this problem is to properly rip the disk, see the accepted answer, for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WMP's Options, on the `Rip Music` tab, there's a checkbox called `Copy protect music`. I assume that this checkbox is/was ticked on your system, causing WMP to add DRM protection to all `.wma` files that are ripped from CD. As a result, these files can't be played anymore when the required DRM licenses aren't present anymore, for example, after switching to a new PC.

The only solution is to untick `Copy protect music` and rip the CDs again.

Comment: It's a shame I gave the cd's to sue ryder after I had ripped them! Thanks so much for telling me what you did. 

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft themselves has a tool which removes the DRM from WMA files:
It's called
**Digital Rights Update Tool**
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/digital-rights-update-tool/9nblggh52q93