# WMA audio files with DRM--I have the original disk

Tags: audio, windows-media-player, audio-recording, drm, wma

I am in a situation described several times by SuperUsers in their posts, for example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1301935/digital-music-rights-content-usage-rights). Basically, many years ago, I copied some music from a CD to my system using the WMA format, unintentionally and unfortunately with DRM. When I changed computers years later, I never noticed that those audio files became locked due to the DRM. The old computer is long gone.

But I still have the original CD! As my luck would have it, however, it's badly scratched. I am able to burn 7 of the 8 tracks successfully (this time without DRM!) but the eighth track copies poorly.

I would prefer if I could "unlock" the old file if I could only find a way to pull a license key or something from the CD.

Question: is there a way to do this--"unlock" an old copy of a DRM'd WMA audio file using the original CD which is scratched?

Thanks!

EDIT: Thinking out loud, I understand that my old Windows Media Player stored something like unique, one-time license keys to those old files somewhere in its directories, so without the WMP application, I have permanently lost access to my files. Or, could it be the other way around--do the files have written into them something like keys so that files + original CD = success?

I am searching around, hoping for some alternative solutions. For example, peraps I will be able to burn the CD again with DRM and swap the new track for the old track, then be able to play it in such a DRM setting. Then while streaming, I would copy the file. Perhaps even use a program to remove the DRM all together--that would be ideal.

Comment: *"I would prefer if I could "unlock" the old file if I could only find a way to pull a license key or something from the CD."* - I don't believe this would be a necessary step. Assuming you have Windows 10 (and can thus install apps from the Windows Apps store), you may want to look at [this official tool from Microsoft for removing WMA DRM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/digital-rights-update-tool/9nblggh52q93?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

Comment: @Anaksunaman Thank you for the advice, I do have Windows 10 and i have installed the app "Digital Rights Update Tool" from the store. Unfortunately, it sees "no .wma files with removable copy protection were found" I am certain I used WMP to burn the CD, so something weird is going on.

Comment: The license keys are indeed stored in one of WMP's directories (`C:\Users\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows\DRM` if I remember correctly). Without these keys, it's unfortunately impossible to play the DRM-protected files - having the original CD doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Something that's still worth a try is trying a different CD ripping program, as WMP does a poor job of handling damaged CDs. I would suggest [Exact Audio Copy](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/), as it can make use of the CD drive's error information (L2) while ripping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Windows 10, you can use Microsoft's "[Digital Rights Update Tool](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/digital-rights-update-tool/9NBLGGH52Q93)" to remove that particular DRM:

> The Digital Rights Update Tool removes the copy protection you added when ripping CDs to the .wma format from within Windows Media Player. Other forms of copy protection cannot be removed.